# How to add section in grouped table view?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to add section in table view. but I got a fatal error. What's wrong in my code? Any better way to do this?

This is my reference: https://github.com/KoheiHayakawa/DateCell
but the reference has no section. How to add section programmatically?

```
let kDateCell = "dateCell1"
let kDatePickerCell = "datePickerCell1"
let kOtherCell = "otherCell1"

var dateArray : [[String: AnyObject]] = []
var dateArray2 : [[String: AnyObject]] = []
```

viewDidLoad

```
    //Section 1
    let itemOne = [titleKey: "Start Time", dateKey: nextFirst] as [String : Any]
    let itemTwo = [titleKey: "End Time", dateKey: nextFirst] as [String : Any]
    let itemThree = [titleKey: "Apply to All"]
    self.dateArray = [itemOne as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, itemTwo as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, itemThree as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
    
    //Section 2
    let dayOne = [titleKey: "31/8"]
    let dayTwo = [titleKey: "1/9"]
    let dayThree = [titleKey: "2/9"]
    let dayFour = [titleKey: "3/9"]
    let dayFive = [titleKey: "4/9"]
    let daySive = [titleKey: "5/9"]
    let daySeven = [titleKey: "6/9"]
    
    self.dateArray2 = [dayOne as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, dayTwo as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, dayThree as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>,dayFour as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, dayFive as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, daySive as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, daySeven as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    if (self.hasInlineDatePicker()) {
        return dateArray.count + 1;
    }else if(section == 1){
        return dateArray2.count
    }
    return 9
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell: UITableViewCell?
    var cellID = kOtherCell
    
    if (self.indexPathHasPicker(indexPath)) {
        cellID = kDatePickerCell;
    } else if (self.indexPathHasDate(indexPath)) {
        cellID = kDateCell;
    }
    
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID)

    var modelRow = indexPath.row
    if (self.datePickerIndexPath != nil && self.datePickerIndexPath!.row <= indexPath.row) {
        modelRow -= 1
    }
    //fatal error: Index out of range here.
    let itemData = self.dateArray[modelRow]
    
    if (cellID == kDateCell) {
        cell!.textLabel!.text = itemData[titleKey] as? String
        cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = self.dateFormatter.string(from: itemData[dateKey] as! Date)
    } else if (cellID == kOtherCell) {
        cell!.textLabel!.text = itemData[titleKey] as? String
    }

    return cell!
    
}
```

This is the app layout.
[image: Layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a section programmatically, you want to use one of the following methods:

```
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
```

or

```
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
optional public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

The first one will add a default header section with a `UILabel`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 0 {
        return "Next week\nDate...."
    } else {
        return "Specific date and time"
    }
}
```

The second one will give you more option since you can inject your own custom `UIView`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let customHeaderView = MyCustomHeaderView()

    // configure custom view

    return customHeaderView
}
```

---

Edit: If you're having more than one section, you also need to implement the following method (which you already have):

```
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
optional public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

ex:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```